# Etat HTTP 415 - Unsupported Media Type : GET not reaching Jersey REST

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, jersey

I'm using Spring MVC with hibernate. I have a RESTful web service, written using Jersey, that looks like this:

```
 @GET  
  @Path("/interets/{idCentre}/annonces") 
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public List<Annonce> getAnnonceParCentre(@PathParam(value="idCentre") int idCentre){
      return metier.getAnnonceParCentre(idCentre);
   }
```

This is my Annonce class:

```
package ma.ensa.model;
import java.util.Date;
public class Annonce implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer idAnnonce;
private String libelleAnnonce;
private double prixAnnonce;
private Date dateAnnonce;
private double positionX;
private double positionY;
private double positionZ;
private int idCentre;
private String description;
private int idVille;
private int idPersonne;
private CentreInteret centreInteret;

public Annonce() {
}

public Annonce(String libelleAnnonce, double prixAnnonce, Date dateAnnonce, double positionX, double positionY,
        double positionZ, int idCentre, String description, int idVille, int idPersonne, CentreInteret centreInteret) {
    this.libelleAnnonce = libelleAnnonce;
    this.prixAnnonce = prixAnnonce;
    this.dateAnnonce = dateAnnonce;
    this.positionX = positionX;
    this.positionY = positionY;
    this.positionZ = positionZ;
    this.idCentre = idCentre;
    this.description = description;
    this.idVille = idVille;
    this.idPersonne = idPersonne;
}

public Integer getIdAnnonce() {
    return this.idAnnonce;
}

public void setIdAnnonce(Integer idAnnonce) {
    this.idAnnonce = idAnnonce;
}

public String getLibelleAnnonce() {
    return this.libelleAnnonce;
}

public void setLibelleAnnonce(String libelleAnnonce) {
    this.libelleAnnonce = libelleAnnonce;
}

public double getPrixAnnonce() {
    return this.prixAnnonce;
}

public void setPrixAnnonce(double prixAnnonce) {
    this.prixAnnonce = prixAnnonce;
}

public Date getDateAnnonce() {
    return this.dateAnnonce;
}

public void setDateAnnonce(Date dateAnnonce) {
    this.dateAnnonce = dateAnnonce;
}

public double getPositionX() {
    return this.positionX;
}

public void setPositionX(double positionX) {
    this.positionX = positionX;
}

public double getPositionY() {
    return this.positionY;
}

public void setPositionY(double positionY) {
    this.positionY = positionY;
}

public double getPositionZ() {
    return this.positionZ;
}

public void setPositionZ(double positionZ) {
    this.positionZ = positionZ;
}

public int getIdCentre() {
    return this.idCentre;
}

public void setIdCentre(int idCentre) {
    this.idCentre = idCentre;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return this.description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public int getIdVille() {
    return this.idVille;
}

public void setIdVille(int idVille) {
    this.idVille = idVille;
}

public int getIdPersonne() {
    return this.idPersonne;
}

public void setIdPersonne(int idPersonne) {
    this.idPersonne = idPersonne;
}
}
}
```

Method in DaoAnnonce Class:

```
@Override
public List<Annonce> getAnnonceParCentre(int id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query qr = session.createQuery("from Annonce where idCentre=:id").setInteger("id",id);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Annonce> crs = qr.list();
    session.close();
    return crs;
}
```

When I'm trying to do a  GET : http://localhost:8080/projet_stage_v1/rs/interets/2/annonces

**root cause:**

```
    Grave: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2766)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2682)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1308)
at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.readFrom(JacksonProviderProxy.java:139)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:488)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:46)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:183)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending an Accept header with your GET request? Its value should be application/json

Comment: Yes. I add  "Content-Type: application/json" but not work. when i try with http://localhost:8080/projet_stage_v1/rs/annonces for example without parameter i get the result "OK" , but when try with parameter i get the error.I dont understand why??

Comment: Accept is different than Content-type. Try it with "Accept: application/json". Content-type is irrelevant for GET requests since they have no request body. Accept is what is mapped to your "@Produces" annotation. Content-type is mapped to "@Consumes" annotations.

Comment: I get another error :   **Grave: A message body reader for Java class int, and Java type int, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/octet-stream**